# How can I set a yarn version-tag-prefix and version-git-message per project?

Tags: git, npm, yarnpkg

Yarn has a [handy versioning config](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/version/) which allows you to configure git when a tag is created during versioning:

```
yarn config set version-tag-prefix "v"
yarn config set version-git-message "v%s"
```

However, I have a project with multiple npm projects inside of it and I want to version each with `project-vn.n.n` and the above seems to be a global setting.

Is there a way to configure the prefix and message per package.json (without having to manually specify it)?

Answer (score 9):

So, I just faced that exact same issue and found a way to fix it.

The short answer is that you can create a file `.yarnrc` in each project directory, with the following content:

```
# example of myrepo/workspace1/.yarnrc

version-tag-prefix workspace-1-v
version-git-message "workspace-1 v%s"
```

That way when running `yarn publish` from the workspace directory, or `yarn workspaces run publish` from the root of the repository yarn use `workspace1/.yarnrc` configuration.

A way to see where yarn is looking for config files is to run `yarn <command> --verbose`.

[image]